# Asp.Net-Core - OutputFormatter to format decimal result to two decimal places

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm working on implementing a custom output formatter for decimal type properties of a class, it should return two decimal places always. 
For example: value = 5 , then it should be 5.00.
I'm creating a custom OutputFormatter in Asp.net Core, however, when I apply the override for CanWriteType, my code method (WriteResponseBodyAsync) is never hit. If I remove that CanWriteType method, then it hits the WriteResponseBodyAsync method, but the context.Object contains all the class, not only the decimal properties of it.

How can I make this OutputFormatter work with all decimal properties in responses?
Any help will be appreciated.

```
public class CustomDecimalFormatter : OutputFormatter
{
    public string ContentType { get; private set; }
    public CustomDecimalFormatter(){
        ContentType = "application/json";
        SupportedMediaTypes.Add(MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json"));

        }

    protected override bool CanWriteType(Type type)
    {
        return type == typeof(decimal);
    }

    public override Task WriteResponseBodyAsync(OutputFormatterWriteContext context)
    {
        var response = context.HttpContext.Response;
        var decimalValue = (decimal)context.Object;

        var formatted = decimalValue.ToString("F2", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(writeStream))
        {
            writer.Write(formatted);
        }

        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your CanWriteType(Type) method is checking to see if the type is Nullable<decimal>, but you're attempting to convert context.Object to just decimal. What are the types of the properties in your class, decimal or Nullable<decimal>?

Comment: It can be decimal? or decimal, anyways, I would like it works for any of them.

Comment: That should be as simple as "return type == typeof(decimal) || type == typeof(decimal?);" in CanWriteType, and change the cast in WriteResponseBodyAsync() to "(decimal?)" instead of "(decimal)", which will cast it to Nullable<decimal> if it's a decimal. Then you just handle it as a Nullable<decimal> which may or may not have a value. Nullable<> does not accept a format string in its ToString() method, so just do var formatted = decimalValue.HasValue ? decimalValue.Value.ToString("F2", CultureInfo.InvarianCulture) : string.Empty;

Comment: The issue is not with decimal nullable or not. My issue is how I get the code hit for decimal properties ? Review my methods and class code.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any problem in your methods and class code. But adding your `CustomDecimalFormatter` at the beginning of `OutputFormatters` list will fix the problem. To achieve this, add this line of code in `ConfigureServices` method in Startup.cs:

```
services.AddMvc( options => {
                 options.OutputFormatters.Insert(0,new CustomDecimalFormatter());
            });
```